# How to interpolate ruby inside of an interpolated bit of ruby in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a situation where one user makes message templates and another one can plug in values. I'm using the best_in_place gem, which will allow a user to edit the message on the show page.

The problem is this. When I call the message, with the required erb to make the gem work, it treats all of this as a regular string, not as ruby.

This is unclear, I'm sorry.

Here's the code.

```
@announcement.content = "The <%= best_in_place @announcement, :train %> is arriving in five minutes."

/show.html.erb

<%= @announcement.content %>
```

I want it to put "The click to set train is arriving in five minutes." and if the user clicks where it says "click to set train," a text field will open for them to edit (this is something the best-in-place gem does).

Instead, it puts "The <%= best_in_place @announcement, :train %> is arriving in five minutes."

I understand why it is doing this, but I don't know how to make it instead interpret the ruby I'm trying to pass in.

Ideas?

Comment: Why can't you do this as a partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fact that I wasn't clear made it hard to answer this question.
What I'm doing is transforming user-inputted text (using a method in the model, called by the controller) to replace certain keywords with erb tags that call the best_in_place plugin. In my view, when presenting this content to another user, I wanted to call this content, which is saved as an attribute in the database, in such a way that it would render correctly for the other user to have the best_in_place functionality active.

Here's what I ended up doing. It is working, but if you have better ideas, please let me know.

In the announcements#create view, the user creates an announcement with certain pre-defined blocks of bracketed text as well as free-input text. For example, they might write "[train] is leaving from [platform] in [time] minutes."

When they hit save, the controller's create action calls the construct_message method from the model. It looks like this:

```
def construct_message(msg)
    msg.gsub! '[train]', '<%= best_in_place @announcement, :train_id, :as => :select, collection: Train::list_trains, place_holder: "Click here to set train." %>' #note: list_trains and list_platforms are methods on the model, not really important...
    msg.gsub! '[platform]', '<%= best_in_place @announcement, :platform_id, :as => select, collection: Platform::list_platforms, placeholder: "Click here to set platform." %>'
    msg.gsub! '[time]', '<%= best_in_place @announcement, :number_of_minutes, placeholder: "Click here to set." %>'
end
```

Then, when I want to show that attribute in my view, I'm using render :inline, like this.

on announcements/:id

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <% announcement = @announcement %>
    <%= render :inline => announcement.content, locals: { :announcement => announcement } %>
</p>
```

This allows the erb call that I wrote into the attribute to be functional.
Also note that I'm choosing to use a local rather than instance variable here; this is because in announcements#index, I also render this text and the table there uses local variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular old string interpolation:

```
@announcement.content = "The #{best_in_place @announcement, :train} is arriving in five minutes."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ERB to render any ERB template string. In this case something like:

```
<%= ERB.new(@announcement.content).result %>
```

Although you likely won't have access to all your Rails helpers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way to do this:

```
@announcement.content_type = :arriving
```

Later:

```
<%= render(partial: @announcement.content_type)
```

In `_arriving.erb`:

```
The <%= best_in_place @announcement, :train %> is arriving in five minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: ERB is not Ruby, and Rails uses both at different times.**

You want simple Ruby string interpolation here:

```
@announcement.content = "The #{best_in_place @announcement, :train} is arriving in five minutes."
```

---

> This is unclear, I'm sorry.

Not to worry, the Rails framework throws so many different new concepts at you it can be frustrating for newcomers.

Start from this: the Ruby framework builds the answer to the user's browser from a collection of resources  Each file is evaluated by an interpreter for its own language. The trick is: look at the extension.

Files ending in `.coffee` will be compiled into javascript, files ending in `.scss` will become CSS, and in the same way files ending in `.erb` will yield HTML.
ERB is a language composed of *mostly* HTML already, plus a tag that allows you to interpolate Ruby. ERB stands for [Embedded Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby).

What about files ending in `.rb`, like the file in which you (surely) are evaluating `@announcement.content = "The <%= best_in_place[...]"` (a controller, I guess)?
Well, that's just pure Ruby :) that's why the ERB interpolation syntax `<%= ... >` is not recognized.

What you want to do in the controller, is (as you're trying to do) preparing the data for the view. The ruby in the `<%= ... >` tag in ERB will have access to the controller's instance variables, i.e. the variables with an `@` in front defined in the controller. But to define those, inside the controller, you should rely on Ruby alone.

**Take-home message:**

Be aware of which language you are writing in at each moment. For example:

```
# show.html.erb
<p>Here is ERB, which will be interpreted straight into HTML</p>
<% "Inside the '<% ...' tag is Ruby, but results won't show up in the HTML because there's no '<%='."%>
<% which_language = "Ruby" # Even variable assignments, and comments, do work %> 
<%= "Inside the '<%=' tag, you're writing and interpolating #{which_language} :)" %>
```